# How to save a screen shot of the contents of an FMX component

Tags: delphi, screenshot, firemonkey

Delphi 12 FMX

```
  try
    Bmp := MyFMXLayout.MakeScreenshot;
    try
      Bmp.SaveToFile(C:\temp\mygraphic.bmp');
    finally
      Bmp.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
```

This code results in a .BMP file that is all black in the shape of the TLayout.

How do I correctly capture a screenshot of the contents of an FMX component?

The contents in this case are buttons (child components of the TLayout) with Timages (child components of the SpeedButtons.

To make a minimal reproducible example, name a TLayout to MyFMXLayout and drop a TSpeedbutton on the layout. Then drop a TImage on the button and give the Timage an graphic to display.

Comment: This code has a syntax error and the variables are undefined. The purpose of a code extract is to let others reconstruct what you experience - everything that's left undefined may yield different results.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue. A few lines of code out of any context and a somewhat vague problem description do not benefit anyone.

Comment: The TLayout has buttons set as children. The buttons have TImages set as children of the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you're getting an all-black result because a `TLayout` has no appearance.  On a form or etc., a `TLayout` is not black because what you're seeing is the control behind it.

Put, say, a `TRectangle` on it, and whatever other controls you want, and your bitmap should show those.

Comment: There are graphic elements on that TLayout.

What I'm expecting is a bitmap of the screen shot of the components on that TLayout.

Comment: @Philip I can confirm your assessment, that a `TLayout` has no background. As a result the background on the bitmap will be black, even though the layout appears on the screen to have the color of whatever is behind the layout. A further consequence if the layout is placed on a, say light gray form, is that any object drawn in black color on the layout will show fine on the screen but will not show on the bitmap as the black pen color blends with the black background of the bitmap.

Comment: @MikeatBookup, are the components set as children of the layout, or just happen to be sitting over it?  The screenshot of the layout will only show controls that have the layout as their parent (or grandparent, etc.).  I just tried a `TLayout` with two buttons situated within its boundaries, but only one with the `TLayout` as parent, and the screenshot was black apart from that _one_ button.  Beyond that, as another commenter said, please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @PhilipJ.Rayment I would provide a minimal reproducible example but I don't know how to post it here. How do I post an *image* that is loaded into a TImage that is parented by a TSpeedButton that is parented by a TLayout?

Comment: Often just posting the code and a description will suffice.  But you can also post the content of the .dfm file, and if the image is applied at design time, that image will be in the .dfm file (as hex characters, so don't make it too big, although for a normal speed button it's not likely to be big).  If needed, you can add images to your question (as Tom Brunberg has done in his answer).  But I'll also try your more-detailed explanation and see what I get.

Comment: @MikeatBookup I just tried it again placing a `TSpeedButton` on a `TLayout` and placing a `TImage` on that, and loading an image (at design time) into that `TImage`, and generating a bitmap from the layout, and it worked as expected.  The bitmap was black except where the image was, which showed as expected.  You'll need that minimal reproducible example so we can try exactly what you're trying.

Answer (score 0):

A `TLayout` has no content initially, especially not a background. When placed on a form, it will show whatever is on the form behind it. When you call `MyFMXLayout.MakeScreenshot` the color of the form, or any drawing element behind the `TLayout` will not be considered, as they would not be part of the `TLayout`. Instead, an area without any drawing elements is considered black (because a null color of a bitmap is displayed as black).

Now, if you draw your lines and figures with a black pen, they will not be visible against the black background.

Therefore, You must either fill the background with a color, e.g. white, before you draw your shapes in black. You can do that by adding a filled rectangle before any drawing.

Alternatively you can leave the background black and draw your shapes with a white (or other light) color.

Here's an example of a non colored bg with various shapes and some text as a running program:

[image]

and as a stored bitmap:

[image]

and finally corrected for a similar appearance as in the running program, by adding a light rectangle on which the drawing elements are drawn

[image]